# Cannot find dll function written in asm

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, dll

my code is:

```
HINSTANCE hDll;
hDll = LoadLibrary("FibAsmLib");
myCppProc = GetProcAddress(hDll, "GetFive");
```

library is loaded corectly, but GetProcAddress returns NULL value.

this is how my dll look:

fibAsm.asm

```
.486
.model flat, stdcall
.code

GetFive proc
ret 5
GetFive endp
end
```

asmLib.h

```
#ifdef FIBASMLIB_EXPORTS
#define FIBASMLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FIBASMLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

FIBASMLIB_API int GetFive();
```

and asmLib.def

```
LIBRARY "FibAsmLib"
EXPORTS
GetFive
```

I cannot find where is the problem, have you any clue?

//edit

when I run dll in DependencyWalker i got errors:

```
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
```

now im sure its fault of dll, but still i cannot find out what is wrong

//edit2
i have entry point:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

// edit3
ah, i didnt set .def file as module definition file, but now i cannot compile library cus of

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol GetFive   ...FibAsmLib.def
```

Comment: can you open the dll with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check what is exported?

Comment: i have edited my post including answer for your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a couple of problems. First of all, a DLL needs an entry point (traditionally named `DllMain`) that takes 12 bytes of arguments, so you'll want to add at least one more function for that.

Second, at least as far as I've ever been able to figure out/get things to work, to export an un-mangled name, you need to use the `external=internal` syntax in the `exports` statement, so your .def file should look something like this:

```
LIBRARY "FibAsmLib"
EXPORTS
    GetFive = _GetFive@0
    DllMain =  _DllMain@12
```

Without that, a .def file with `exports GetFive` finds the GetFive function you wrote, but exports the mangled name for it (`_GetFive@0`). That works fine, but if you do that, you need to specify the mangled name when you call `GetProcAddress`:

```
myCppProc = GetProcAddress(hDll, "_GetFive@0");
```

Anyway, when you do the link you'll also need to specify the entry point, something like:

```
link fibAsm.obj /def:asmLib.def /entry:DllMain
```

As an aside, when/if you want to see the names exported from a DLL, the easiest way is usually to use `dumpbin /exports YouDll.dll` (obviously replacing `YourDll.dll` with the name of the actual DLL file you want to look at). Warning: for a large DLL, the output can be quite voluminous so you often want to pipe output to something like `less`.

You don't actually need to export the entry point though (in fact, I think at least some versions of the linker give a warning if you do) so the overall files can look like this:

fibasm.asm

```
.486
.model flat, stdcall

.code

Entry PROC Inst : DWORD, reason : DWORD, reserved : DWORD
ret 12
Entry ENDP

GetFive PROC
ret 5
GetFive ENDP

end
```

asmlib.def:

```
LIBRARY "FibAsmLib"
EXPORTS
    GetFive = _GetFive@0
```

makefile:

```
fibasmlib.dll: fibasm.obj asmlib.def
    link fibAsm.obj /def:asmLib.def /entry:Entry

.asm.obj:
    ml /c $<
```

At least for me, with these three in place, a `nmake -a` builds the DLL successfully.

Comment: how should i name that external export? is it _FuncName@Number? is number any value?

Comment: @Naix: The number is the number of bytes of parameters expected by the function (thus the `@0` for `GetFive`, and `@12` for `DllMain`).

Comment: after all steps i got: FibAsmLib.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GetFive@0

Comment: Just as additional information, DllMain is optional: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

"LoadLibrary" seems not to return NULL - if I understand you correctly.

This means that "DllMain" was not an issue; otherwise LoadLibrary would have returned NULL.

Many linkers want an underscore in the function names; if you name a function "GetFive" in the .DEF file then the linker will expect a function actually named "_GetFive" because all C compilers will add that underscore to each function.

Maybe the "stdcall" in the assembler code is the problem. This may tell the assembler to automatically generate symbol names. This means: The assembler will rename "GetFive" to "_GetFive@0" (in this case maybe the function must be named "GetFive@0" without underscore in the .DEF file).

To avoid this I would use "cdecl" instead of "stdcall" in the assembler ALTHOUGH the function actually is a stdcall function! Doing so it will not be possible to call C code from assembler within the DLL and vice versa. (C code in the EXE file can call assembler code in the DLL).

The "objdump" tool coming with the GNU C compiler can be used to check the names of functions in object and DLL files:

This command will list all names of symbols (functions and variables) in an object file:

```
objdump -t FibAsmLib.obj
```

You can see if your function is named "GetFive", "_GetFive" or "_GetFive@0".

This command will list all Windows specific information from a DLL file:

```
objdump -p FibAsmLib.dll
```

This tool makes a really long output. Somewhere in the middle of the output you'll find a list of all exports (of all functions that can be accessed using "GetProcAddress"). This list will look like this:

```
[Ordinal/Name Pointer] Table
        [   0] GetFive
```

By the way: "ret 5" does not make any sense! I think the instruction should be "ret 20". However this would lead to a protection fault, not to a problem with "GetProcAddress".